# Errors running Google API calendar example for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

When I try to run [this example](https://codereview.appspot.com/7007048/patch/13001/14003) in VBExpress 2010, I get the following intellisense errors.

```
scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue())
```

This line generates:

> Error 7   Overload resolution failed because no accessible
>   'GetStringValue' is most specific for these arguments:
>       Extension method 'Public Function GetStringValue() As String' defined in 'Google.Apis.Util.Utilities': Not most specific.
>       Extension method 'Public Function GetStringValue() As String' defined in 'Google.Apis.Util.Utilities': Not most specific.

Additionally, these two lines each generate a "not defined" error.

```
Dim credentials As FullClientCredentials = promptingClientCredentials.EnsureFullClientCredentials()
Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer()
```

> Error 9   Type 'BaseClientService.Initializer' is not defined.
>   Error 8   Type 'FullClientCredentials' is not defined.

Finally, this line:

```
Dim state As IAuthorizationState = AuthorizationMgr.GetCachedRefreshToken(STORAGE, KEY)
```

generates the error:

> Error 15  'AuthorizationMgr' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
>   due to its protection level.

As to the first error, both `google.apis.silverlight.google.apis.util.utilities` and `google.apis.google.apis.util.utilities` has a `GetStringValue(system.enum) as String` method.

Any ideas about any of these errors?

UPDATE: Excluding Silverlight dll seems to resolve first error ("Not most specific")

Comment: As you updated your post, you should add only reference to Google.Apis assembly.
With which version of the library do you work? 1.3.0-beta? Did you add "Imports Google.Apis.Util" for using the "GetStringValue" extension method?

Comment: Yes, using 1.3.0-beta.  I had included "Imports Google.Apis.Util" and all other imports in the example.  The "not most specific" error is resolved, as noted above.  However, the other 2 errors - - "BaseClientService.Initializer" and "FullClientCredentials" undefined - - remain.

Comment: After manually adding Google.Api.Samples.Helper.dll (did not seem to be part of zip download of 1.3.0-beta), errors now down to 2:  "Dim credentials As FullClientCredentials = PromptingClientCredentials.EnsureFullClientCredentials()" still generates Error 1 Type 'FullClientCredentials' is not defined. And  "state = AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, scopes.ToArray())" now generates Error 3 'RequestNativeAuthorization' is not a member of 'Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.AuthorizationMgr'.

Comment: It's weird. Can you please check something - I think that this problem occurred because you are using VS 2010 Express. I have a VB.NET sample (which wasn't committed yet to the samples repository) which works for me, I just want to check it that one works for you as well. Can you please download it? It's available in the following link - https://codereview.appspot.com/7007048/. Remember to add the right references from the samples repository (DotNetOpenAuth, Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2, Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 and Newtonsoft.Json.Net35). Sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: I think that this is the same example I was using.  In any event, I (re)downloaded it and get the same 2 intellisense errors: at    Dim credentials As FullClientCredentials = PromptingClientCredentials.EnsureFullClientCredentials(), FullClientCredentials is marked as undefined and I am asked if I want to change it to Net.ICredentials; at           state = AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, scopes.ToArray()), I am told RequestNativeAuthorization is not a member of google.apis.samples.helper.authorizationmagr  (requestauthorization(system.uri) is closest method)  thks for help

Comment: Can you try run it in VS Express 2012 or VS Professional edition? What is you OS?

Comment: I am running Windows 7. I downloaded and tried to run example on VS 2012 Express.  I get the same errors.  When I look at Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.AuthorizationMgr in both 2010 and 2012, there is no "RequestNativeAuthorization" method, only "RequestAuthorization(System.Uri) As String"  It may be that Google has just made this too complicated for a casual user like me.

Comment: RequestNativeAuthorization gets a list of strings (scopes). But you were complaining about GetCachedRefreshToken - doest that work for you now? I'm aware that the current OAuth2 is not intuitive at all. We are going to simplify it and rewrite our own OAuth2 library soon.

Comment: No, the problems have always been 'PromptingClientCredentials.EnsureFullClientCredentials()' generates Error 1 Type 'FullClientCredentials' is not defined and state = 'AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization(client, scopes.ToArray())'  generates Error 3 'RequestNativeAuthorization' is not a member of 'Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.AuthorizationMgr'  As to the latter, the AuthorizationMgr dll just does not include the RequestNativeAuthorization method, only RequestAuthorization.  Where  can I re-download Google.Apis.Samples.Helper.AuthorizationMgr to insure latest version?

Comment: Our samples repository is available in the following address: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples, and the AuthorizationManager - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/SampleHelper/AuthorizationMgr.cs?repo=samples. Something is really weird in your case - I suggest that you will open an issue regarding this problem in our issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list, and hopefully we will get into it soon. Thanks and sorry...

Answer (score 0):

We just published a new sample using VB.NET and OAuth2.
It works in VS Professional 2012. Take a look - http://samples.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/README.html